# An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.RunQuery()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I tried looking for lead to finding the cause if this error but I seem can't to find one:

Here is the stack trace:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$UnknownException: An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.RunQuery().
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:518)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:452)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:493)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:490)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$Query.propertyNameSize()I
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService.runQuery(LocalDatastoreService.java:1053)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:498)
```

I get this error when trying to persist a `Objectify` registered `@Entity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NoSuchMethodError is almost always a result of having code that was compiled against one jar version but then run against a different jar version.  Perhaps you have an old version of the GAE SDK?

Comment: Yes it looks like the AppEngine version I have in the POM and the App Engine library in the build path is different